# Not able to connect by frontend to backend on heroku after successful deployment

Tags: reactjs, heroku, mern

I have deployed my mern stack app on heroku. The problem is i am not able to make any request to my backend .
I am connecting my frontend to my backend like this...

> `API=http://localhost:5000/api`

```
 import { API } from "../../backend";
import { signin } from "../../auth/helper";
export const getAllProducts = () => {
  return fetch(`**${API}/allProducts**`, { method: "GET" })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

I think i am caliing api on my local host thatswhy i am not getting connected to backend.
What should i do here?

If you want anything else you can tell me .

Comment: What are you getting for response? What is the error? Is it 404?

Comment: I am not getting response.because locally it works but on the heroku it csnnot access API

Comment: It is saying failed to fetch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In client side (frontend) code, localhost is the end user's machine because the code runs in the browser of that machine. Therefore, when it's trying to fetch at localhost:5000/api, it's looking for a Node.js server on the end user's machine, not your actual production server on Heroku.

Instead of localhost, use the domain Heroku assigned to your app. You can find it in the Settings of your dyno and should look something like this `https://yourapp.herokuapp.com/`. Additionally, you can use `NODE_ENV` env var to set the API string so it works both on development and production:

```
const API = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'https://yourapp.herokuapp.com/api' : 'http://localhost:5000/api';
```

Comment: Yes yougot it right. I was doing that silly mistake .thanks for getting me correct

Comment: No problem. We all make silly mistakes ;). Did you manage to solve it? Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted